# Typescript SyntaxError on Windows not Linux Ubuntu

Tags: typescript, operating-system, syntax-error, quasar-framework, typescript-eslint

I have a Quasar 2 project using Typescript running in Node 14, the production is published in Windows Server but I'm working locally in Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS with exact same workspace configuration. I had the following code:

```html
<template>
    <q-input
        v-model="obj.prop"
        :rules="[ val => valid( obj.prop as number ) || 'Error' ]"
    />
</template>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">
export default defineComponent( {
    .
    .
    .

    data: () => ( {
        obj: { prop: 0 as number | null },
    } ),

    methods: {
        valid( val: number ): boolean {
            return val > 0;
        },
    },
} );
</script>
```

But for some reason that is compiling fine for me on Ubuntu but not for Windows which is returning the following:

[Terminal Log Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV2kC.png)

In order to avoid it I changed with the following code:

```html
<q-input
    v-model="obj.prop"
    :rules="[ val => valid( obj.prop ) || 'Error' ]"
/>
```

```js
valid( val: number | null ): boolean {
    return val > 0;
}
```

My question is why is it working on Linux Ubuntu the first way but no in Windows? I don't want to use Windows not even create a workspace there. How can I compile in Linux exact the same way Windows does in order to see those errors? I know about WSL 2 but I think it is not the same. It is supposed to be compile exactly the same for any OS, so, I'm confused.

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "extends": "@quasar/app/tsconfig-preset",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [ "DOM", "ES2019.Array" ],
  }
}
```

I already solved, I want to know why it is happening and how to avoid it with my current workspace configuration. Because it took me a lot of time compile it on every OS configuration